# Are there any almost multiperfect numbers for k>2

Tags: number-theory

Define an almost perfect number as any number n such that sigma(n)=2n-1. Define an almost multiperfect number as any number n such that sigma(n)=kn-1 k>1. Besides almost perfect numbers, are there any almost multiperfect numbers? This is related to the question I asked yesterday except  talking about almost perfect numbers instead of quasiperfect numbers.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a deleted user on Reddit claims to have done a brute-force search up to 4 * 10^11 without success: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/govc71/almostmultiperfect_numbers/

Comment: I would not have expected that this has been tested upto such a high limit.